# Unity C# Inheritance get value from child class to parent class then to child class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the `ClicksCounter` from `FableScript` child class' value to another child class and I don't know how to transfer the value. From what I achieved, the `ClicksCounter` are read by the parent class (`GameManagerRevamped`) successfully, but on the `BattleSystem` child class it seems that the values are not transported there.

Assuming this is my Parent Class

```
public class GameManagerRevamped : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ClicksCounter;

    public virtual void firstButtonClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log(ClicksCounter);    
    }
}
```

My Child class which is `FableScript`

```
public class FableScript : GameManagerRevamped
{
    public override void firstButtonClicked()
    {
        ClicksCounter += 1;        
        base.firstButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

And my 3rd child class `BattleSystem` is where I'm trying to get the value of `ClicksCounter`

```
public class BattleSystem : GameManagerRevamped
{
    public void BattleButton()
    {
        //Output is 0 here
        Debug.Log("Battle Counter is" + ClicksCounter);
    }
}
```

My goal is when the user clicks on the button (`FableScript`) it will increment and be read by `BattleSystem`.

Comment: But `FableScript`  and `BattleSystem` are siblings - they both inherit the same class. for what you want to do, `BattleSystem` should inherit `FableScript`.

Comment: Oh I see so nice idea!! :))) Thank you will definetely use!

Comment: So the child class cannot set the value in the parent class and another child class cannot get its value??

Comment: No, the `ClicksCounter` is an instance member, not a static member. If the instance is of type `BattleSystem`, and that derive from `FableScript`, then when `firstButtonClicked` is called on the instance of `BattleSystem`, the code defined in `FableScript` will run (unless overriden in `BattleSystem`.

Comment: That would somehow break the principle of instance variables which belongs to a single instance. What you are thinking of is static so the variable belongs to the class and then, to all instances of the class. What is important is whether you have only one FableScript and how BattleSystem is a GameManagerRevamped type. If unrelated, it would boils down to having a Car inherits from Animal just so you can get the weight of a cat (yes it makes no sense).

Comment: Oh I see xD sorry pretty new in c# and unity hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is the make the click counter static in the base class. This is if it is ok that it shares that property between all child classes.

```
class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var childClass1 = new ChildClass1();
         var childClass2 = new ChildClass2();
         childClass1.IncrementCounter();
         childClass2.ConsoleLogCounter();
      }
   }

   public class BaseClass
   {
      public static int counter;
   }

   public class ChildClass1 : BaseClass
   {
      public void IncrementCounter()
      {
         counter++;
      }
   }

   public class ChildClass2 : BaseClass
   {
      public void ConsoleLogCounter()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(counter);
      }
   }
```

Comment: class program is my parent class??

Comment: No BaseClass is your parent class. The examples shows you how you have two classes inheriting from the same base class. Since the counter in the base class is static it is stored in the base class and accessible from both child classes.

Comment: @NicoleErasga I see you have made many questions lately and gotten many answers. Please accept the answers if they helped you.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't know I had to accept answers xD gotta do it pretty soon :))

Comment: Oh yes!! the static counter is all I need for my problem is now solved :)))